# How to fire an 'if condition' after making an ajax call to a view?

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm building a search bar that searches for objects in my database and if the search finds some matching objects, it then displays the objects in the html page without reloading it. But after I fire the Ajax call and get the tuples from the database, they are not being rendered on the template

So, the flow is like this: I search for 'apple' in the search bar, hit search button and fire the ajax call to my view. After that, I set a boolean value 'search_successful' to 'True' if I find any 'apple' in my database. I then pass it to my template from where I fired the ajax in the first place. Now I am successfully getting the data and the boolean sets to 'True' correctly. Until this point everything works perfect. But after passing the context to my template,  It does not fire the **if condition** that will display the data if **search_successful = True**. All this is carried out by an ajax call without reloading the page.

Here is the **if condition** which I expect to work after the ajax call has been made to print the data:

```
<form  id="search_object">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" id="search_my_object" placeholder="Search Item" id="search_my_object" class="form-control" required="true" style="border-color:#f4511e;"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn btn-lg" style="border-color:#f4511e; background-color:Transparent; color:white; margin-left:47%;">
</form>

{% if search_successful is True %}
    # Just print the retrieved data passed in the context
{% endif %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '#search_object', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '{% url 'daily_object_search' %}',
            data: {
               search_object_name: $('#search_my_object').val(),
               csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data == "true"){
                    alert('This Object is Present');
                }
                else if(data == "invalid_query"){
                    alert("Please enter a valid object to be searched");
                }
                else{
                    alert('This object is not present');
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Views.py :

```
def daily_object_search(request):
    context = {'search_successful': False}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        object_name = request.POST['search_object_name']
        print("The query for search :", object_name)
        if len(object_name) <= 2:
            print("The length of the object name :", len(object_name))
            return HttpResponse('invalid_query')
        my_cursor = mydb.cursor()
        sql = "select * from education_fruits where tag = '" + object_name + "'"
        my_cursor.execute(sql)
        result = my_cursor.fetchall()
        print(result)
        if my_cursor.rowcount <= 0:
            print("No object found")
            return HttpResponse('false')
        context['search_successful'] = True
        # Just append the 'result' data in the context before sending it
    return HttpResponse('true', context)
```

I tried printing the data in the if condition but removed it as it was giving me the mentioned error in the browser console : **XML Parsing Error: syntax error Location: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/daily_object_search
Line Number 1, Column 1**. 
Am I missing something in my understanding of ajax calls and templates?

Comment: yes you are missing something: javascript (and hence also any ajax call you make) runs in the user's browser so there's no template or Django involved. You need to grasp the difference between front-end (the browser) and back-end (your server running python scripts). When using ajax, you want your server (django view) to return a JSON document with whatever data your script needs to update the page. Your javascript is then responsible to add/remove/change DOM elements of the HTML document.

Comment: Is the AJAX call made from a page handled by a different view?

Comment: @dirkgroten okay understood..so is there a way that I can achieve what I want to do or do I need to re-think of how to do it? Any suggestions on the approach?

Comment: @MNSH yes the page is written in one view and the ajax call written in that page is being handled by another view

Answer (score 0):

Does it really have to be a boolean? If not, you can do this and compare strings instead.

**Views.py**

```
context['search_successful'] = "true"
```

**template**

```
{% if search_successful|stringformat:"i" == "true" %}
    # Do whatever
{% endif %}

# stringformat:"i", converts your template variable into String since you want to make sure that you're comparing two objects with the same type.
# You can also change the string, it doesn't have to be "true" you can use "found", "checked" etc.
```